# Maximum and Minimum distance from query point within bounding box

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm reading an article regarding approximating sums using KD-trees (similar to FMM).

As part of the effort I'm trying to make sense of [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f848/6d1be0250a83b447d8ee75043359bcef486f.pdf?_ga=2.159298682.1778656541.1566974675-1838143381.1566818223) , which is cited.

I'm having trouble understanding this part:

> Computing the maximum variation of weights over all points below node
>   ND is easy. We know the location of xquery and we know the bounding
>   hyperrectangle of the current node. A simple algorithm costing
>   O(Number of tree dimensions) can compute the shortest and largest
>   possible distances to any point in the node. From these two values,
>   and the assumption that the weight function is non-increasing, we can
>   compute the minimum and maximum possible weights wmin and wmax of any
>   datapoint below node ND.

The only solution I can think of is to bound the variation (wmax-wmin) from above using the corners of the bounding box, and then computing the distance from the query point to each of the 
 corners is indeed O(d), but there are 2^d corners... But this doesn't seem to be the author's intention. Could anybody point me to what I"m missing here?